# Matplotlib in python: equivalent to fig.set_facecolor in mpl.rcParams?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

If I do:

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_facecolor('#fff1e0')
```

I change the color of the surrounding margins and the background of the axis tick labels.

As I am specifying everything as rcParams:

```
    mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = 'monospace'
    mpl.rcParams['font.size'] = 7
    mpl.rcParams['axes.facecolor'] = 'fff1e0'
    mpl.rcParams['figure.facecolor'] = 'fff1e0'
    mpl.rcParams['figure.edgecolor'] = 'fff1e0'
    mpl.rcParams['axes.edgecolor'] = '6595CC'

    mpl.rcParams['xtick.color'] = '1869B5'
    mpl.rcParams['ytick.color'] = '1869B5'
    mpl.rcParams['grid.color'] = 'EAEFF8'
```

I would like to know which would be the equivalent in rcParams for `fig.set_facecolor`.

Not sure if relevant but matplotlib is being embbeded in Tkinter.

Comment: Is there a good reason for the `tkinter` tag?

Answer (score 0):

The [Artist Tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/intermediate/artists.html#artist-tutorial) states that the Figure contains all Axes so you should use `mpl.rcParams['figure.facecolor']`

The [docs for `Figure`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib-figure-figure) support that :

> facecolor : default: rcParams["figure.facecolor"]

The two methods can be tested by commenting/un-commenting the appropriate lines in the following:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

mpl.rcParams['figure.facecolor'] = 'maroon'

fig = plt.figure()
##fig.set_facecolor('purple')
plt.plot()
plt.show()
plt.close()

# multiple Axes
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,2)
##fig.set_facecolor('purple')
for ax,c in zip(axs.flatten(),['red','green','blue','yellow']):
    ax.set_facecolor(c)
plt.show()
plt.close()

mpl.rcdefaults()
```

---

[Anatomy of a Figure](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#parts-of-a-figure)